# How to use both setxkbmap and xmodmap on Linux Debian i3?

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3-window-manager

I bought new laptop that doesn't have <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys.
I need both keys when I type code in Vim.

I installed Debian with the i3WM desktop environment on my laptop. I remapped my keyboard using the `xmodmap` command to replace <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> and <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> with <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

This works perfectly, but I want a new language in my keyboard. I use `setxkbmap` to set up two layouts: US and IR.

Here is my **i3** configuration:

```
#language
exec "setxkbmap -layout us, ir"
exec "setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'"

#remap keyboard
exec xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

When I restart my computer, I can change my keyboard language with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> but <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> and <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> are not mapped to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

I run the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in my terminal. This works fine but doesn't change my keyboard layout.

How can I fix it so that I can use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem.

First I comment all commands:

```
#language
#exec "setxkbmap -layout us, ir"
#exec "setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'"

#remap keyboard
#exec xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Then add this command:

```
exec_always "/home/milad/.Xmodmap"
```

What is .Xmodmap file? This is a shell script. Content .Xmodmap:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 127 = Home";
xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = End";
xmodmap -e "keycode 223 = Prior";
xmodmap -e "keycode 158 = Next";
```

Now Work fine in any way!